# General chat for philosophy SE seems very inactive

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should something be done to improve the responses from chat room?

It could be helpful for friendly discussion or some relief in anxious or confused moment. Unfortunately the room is very non responsive

Answer (score 0):

That is true. I used to try make it happen that there is regular exchange in the [Symposium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium) back when I had more time at my hands but there was little to no success whatsoever.

If you got any ideas, please come forwards.